# How to change image widget/field in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In Content Types -> xxx -> Manage Fields I have a field named 'Image'. Field type is also 'Image', as well as widget type. All is working but...

Image widget/field I have doesn't allow me to choose image from list of already uploaded... So I need to upload same image every time I want to use it.

I need to also notice that my website is already live, and has some data, so I'm looking for safe replacement. Of course I have staging version of website, which I can test on.

How can I workaround this?

EDIT:
I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources/) Sources module (enable autocomplete or a file browser with [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) module)

Comment: Thanks @Ayesh K! It's good direction: you need to use modules you provided with this module:  http://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield Also files for some reason are available only when you click on '<root>' in Navigation section. But generally it works!